# Merging count(*) from different tables with different WHERE condition

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
OWNERS: pk name
POSTS: pk, post_date, owner_pk
REPLIES: pk,reply_date, post_pk,owner_pk,comment_count
```

Between two dates: date1 and date2 I want a result as:

OWNER:name COUNT(posts) SUM(comment_count)

My problem is that I can't understand how to write a single query that sums the POSTS REPLIES tables separatly.

Ex: Day1 a post is done with 2 comments. Day2 a post is done with no comments. The reply table stores the total number of comments for a given post/day.

```
PostA     Day1
CommentA1 Day1 
CommentA2 Day1 
PostB     Day2
CommentA3 Day2
PostC     Day3
```

Running the query for Day1:

```
Owner:Name count(post) sum(comment_count)
OwnerName  1           2
```

Running the query for Day2:

```
OwnerName  1         1
```

Running the query for Day3:

```
OwnerName  1         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to provide a bit more detail in your question, but I suspect you're after something like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(posts.pk), COUNT(replies.pk)
  FROM owners, OUTER (posts, OUTER replies)
  WHERE owners.pk = posts.owner_pk
    AND posts.pk = replies.post_pk
    AND (posts.post_date BETWEEN ? AND ? OR replies.reply_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
  GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I've never seen OUTER without JOIN - is that standard?  How can you tell LEFT/RIGHT/FULL?

Comment: It's certainly valid SQL, and the dialect I'm most comfortable with. (I must be a bit old school.) @Michael Frederickson's answer is probably the style you're more familiar with.

Comment: Yeah that's ansi standard, I'm going to look this up.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a `SUM()`, what about a `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.pk) AS posts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.pk) AS replies
FROM
    owners o
    LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.owner_pk = o.pk AND p.post_date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
    LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.post_pk = p.pk AND r.post_date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
GROUP BY
    o.pk,
    o.name
```

Comment: There is no owner_pk column in the replies table as far as I can tell

Comment: @kevev22 its the third column `POSTS: pk, post_date, owner_pk` I added the commas

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The OP is saying the table is REPLIES: reply_date, post_pk. You are using `LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.owner_pk = o.pk`. There is no `r.owner_pk`.

Comment: @kevev22 Thanks, I missed that replies only had a foreign key to posts, and not to owners... also, I'm hoping that replies actually does have a PK, even though the OP didn't mention one...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was a wrong in my example. The reply table does have a foreign_key to owners AND also holds a value of the number of comments for a specific reply/day. In the query I want the COUNT(posts) and SUM(comment_count) for a the given date. Thanks again.